# Naming Important Magical Objects

Tags: magic, weapons

You know how all important objects, like swords,n relics, wands, etc. have special names for them? I'm having trouble doing this. I'm making two groups of weapons,one on classical elements, and another on powers. I need ideas for names for these magical objects. Is there anything you can think of? 
I think this list should be able to help others too. My ideas so far are using dynamism for powers, components for elemental, and bracelet, clamp, or amulet for the objects themselves that hold the magic.

Comment: "... other then ring, totem, artifact, talisman, charm,and amulet?" It sounds weird, but "fetish" also means that. Relic and focus could work, too.

Comment: I think the picture is more distracting than helpful. Also, can you give a few examples of what you had in mind for what the name of an object might be (even if the particular words used in your example are not ones you think would actually get used)? There's also a good chance your question will get closed as being too opinion-based - you might be able to get around that by trying to reword the question to be about how to generate names for magical objects in general, and not just for your story.

Comment: Maybe you could try translating them to something like Latin or into a Germanic language for inspiration. You can sometimes get some pretty good results this way.

Comment: I apologize, but I must vote to close this question.  Asking for name ideas is primarily opinion-based (in other words, there's no best answer other than by popular vote, which is against the Stack Exchange model) and a dictionary will give you synonyms.  You can learn more via our [tour] and [help] pages.  My only advice is to use the Tolkien method: use foreign languages or old-English/French/German words.

Comment: This is surely what a Thesarus is for and there are plenty online (and free).

Comment: The problem with your edit is that you are still asking for ideas and "anything you can think of". I can think of a lot of stuff and all of that would be exactly equally valid, because your criteria say that it's valid if I can think of it. The next person to come along would have a lot of ideas, too. All of them being neither better nor worse than my own. We have a tag about [tag:worldbuilding-resources] and one about [tag:worldbuilding-process]. You might want to rephrase your question in the light of "Where can I find guidelines for naming magical items?" Currently it's still opinion-based.

Comment: As an example, see the question [What are good resources to get fantasy names?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/31637/23159) on our sister site Writing.SE. [My answer](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/31643/23159) for example is about generating names by taking a property and then typing that into a translator until I've found something that sounds good. You could either ask such a process-question to get guidelines for the process or you look at [Database of real historical names](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/91026/28789) and do that with "magical item names"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classical element names

1. ring -> circlet, bands, hoop
2. totem -> emblem, symbol, token
3. artifact -> heirloom, relic, antique, vestige
4. talisman -> (my favorite) juju!, fetish (as Alberto Yagos) points
   out
5. charm -> ...
6. amulet -> periapt, brooch, medallion, scarab
7. Shoulders -> Cloak, Cape, Mantle
8. Torso -> Vest, Vestment, Shirt
9. Waist-> Shirt, Girdle
10. Eyes-> Lenses, Goggles, Spectacles

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the word Inherent Thaumaturgic for the classical items and Imbued Thaumaturgic Items for power based items. The word is a variation of the word Thaumaturge