# Naming fictional places/ cities/ towns/ etc?

Tags: cities

I want to name some fictional places but don't know how. (I'm terrible with names)
Are there any websites/ things i can look at to find good ones?

Comment: Also similar:  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/91026/database-of-real-historical-names/91046#91046

Comment: And maybe helpful:  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4641/how-do-i-go-about-generating-names-for-neighborhoods-in-the-capital-city-in-my-f/4644#4644

Answer (score 1):

http://www.fantasynamegenerators.com/town_names.php

There are also a lot of options and subjects to generate names there, have fun.

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of generators out there, but here are the two I use the most:

Donjon is awesome, lots of generators on that index including city names
http://donjon.bin.sh/index.html

this one is if you're using a real world culture as a base for your in game culture.
http://www.mithrilandmages.com/utilities/CityNames.php