# How to name planets in a sci-fi setting?

Tags: planets, worldbuilding-process

So, I’m working on a Sci-Fi story called The Dark Edge. It focuses on two unlikely friends from different species, the Qualians and the Humans. They discover a Von Nuemann probe from outside the galaxy is planning on destroying all life in the Milky Way. They have to convince both of their specifies respectively that they must join together to fight the alien threat. After 167 billion sentients are killed, they finally win. I plan on including many different human and Qualian owned planets existing, but I don’t really know how to name them. I have names like Kelstar, Amon and Tengelle already names, but I need more. Do any of you guy methods I could try to use in order to name my planets?

Comment: Let me put that another way... all the methods humans use are open to your Qualians, but without knowing everything about Qualian language, culture, religion, and history (especially language), there's no way to answer this question.

Comment: @JBH: I’ll deal with the Qualian planets myself. I need names for human controlled planets

Comment: [Start here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/113675/naming-fictional-places-cities-towns-etc) and follow the duplicate links.  Planets (and places, any place really) are named to honor people, places, diety, mythos, to reflect its locale or the hopes/dreams of the settlers, etc.  Almost any proper noun in any language could be used and, in tandem, any adjective (you can see why these questions get closed, there's no "best way" to do this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm typing on my phone right now, so I can't make this a long answer and I can't access some of the formatting features to make it look pretty.

---

Planets can be named for a variety of reasons, like:

Religion - the ancient Romans named the planets after their gods, because that is what they thought the planets were. Later, when we knew planets were planets, we kept naming celestial bodies in that way, e.g. Pluto.

Discovery - nowadays, humans are boring and we just name planets with the telescope that found them and a series of letters and numbers, e.g. Gliese 124B.

People - this hasn't been used on planets before, but places are often named after the person who discovered them, e.g. America.

Nationality - if the people who discovered a planet hailed from a certain area, they could name the planet after their former home, e.g. New Zealand

Features - the Arctic was so named because it is under the constellation of the bear (Arctos is Latin for bear). When the great southern continent was discovered, they called it Antarctica because it was at the opposite end of the Earth to the Arctic.

Inhabitants - when the Amazon rainforest was first explored by Europeans, they encountered tribal warriors with long hair. These reminded them of the Ancient Greek Amazons, a fierce tribe of fighting women, so they named the jungle Amazonia.

That's all I got for now, I could've written a better answer if I had more time and my PC, though I might edit it tomorrow when I do.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be interested in conlanging?
Pretty much create a language for the species and name it based on that language. It does not have to be an extensive language a simple naming language should fulfill the need.

There is a great video made by Artifexian [to start you off](https://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DsFWc0sBO62c&ved=0ahUKEwjAhL_twMfbAhWnFjQIHSnbCDcQwqsBCCwwAQ&usg=AOvVaw0vhDtI6oMm2G_glsf82gTB)

You may later even use it not only to name planets but other locations like cities or significant events in the history or slang that they use maybe even swear words they call each other.